# MySQL user defined variables as a list

Tags: mysql, variables

How do I set a variable in MySQL to be a list of variables in the most standard way?
For example I have a table with 5 records and with 2 columns:
`1. 'id' (primary key)`

`2. 'name'`

And I would like to select the 2 records with a given list of ids from the table:
I would like to do:
`set @ids = (1 ,3);`
`select * from table_name t where t.id in @ids`;

I know I can work around it in several ways, but is it possible to do it this way?
Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score -1):

This is too long for a comment
Usually you would do it in your application,it will be faster

```
WHERE id in (" . implode(',', $id) . ")"
```

But you can use FIND_IN _SET,here is a demo

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83d3/2)

Comment: can u tell me. here `$id` means? @ids = (1 ,3);??

Comment: FIND_IN_SET would have been a good option but it is only compatible with strings, not with ints

Comment: @user3592715 You either split it in code or use quotes.There is no other way.

Comment: You are using PHP, question concerns MySQL.